# Rudin. "Functional Analysis", Theorem 1.18

Tags: functional-analysis

If $\Lambda$ is a linear functional on a TVS, which is not necessarily normed, what does the following statement mean:

> (d) $\Lambda$ is bounded in some neighbourhood $V$ of $0$.

---

For people with access to the book, concerning (d) $\implies$ (a), does he assume the existence of a norm when he writes:

> If (d) holds then $| \Lambda x|< M$ holds for all $x\in X$ and some $M < \infty$.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: $|\Lambda x| < M$ is a statement about real numbers, so there doesn't need to be a norm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Being bounded is a statement about the image of the functional $\Lambda$, which is a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$. Since $V$ is not necessarily normed, the book makes no mention of $|x|$ -- the norm of an element in $V$, but only $|\Lambda x|$ -- the norm of a real/complex number.

Comment: D'oh! I am an idiot; thank you.